# Why firebug shows some javascript objects in red color?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I am trying to learn and improve my javascript skills.

A very helpful tool is firebug, with which i can inspect different javascript objects.

However, i have some questions:

1. Some object names (like jQuery, $, fn etc.) are displayed in red color. Why?
2. Some other objects has a "prototype" property, which is not in bold. What is that and when is good or not to use/implement it?
3. Most of functions are shown as "function()". But there are also some other functions which are displayed, for example, as "u(M)", "z()", "B(E)". Why they are different?

[image: Firebug Console]

Thank you

Comment: Please, add images to your post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

from the [documentation page](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/DOM_Panel) of firebug:

Different color codes let you distinguish between the different types of variables and improve readability. Here they are in detail:

```
Format        Description
Bold Black    Objects
Black         DOM objects
get in gray   "Getter" functions
Bold green    User functions
Green         DOM functions
Bold Red      Constructor functions
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at the [FirebugWiki](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/FAQ#What_do_the_different_colors_of_the_variables_mean.3F)

```
 Bold Red are constructor functions
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'prototype' property is a built-in feature that links to the structure of the object. In JS everything is an object, even functions, and by accessing the prototype property you can extend the object.

[How does JavaScript .prototype work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)